# Error in hosting Angular Universal in IIS : iisnode encountered an error when processing the request

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, angular-universal, iisnode

I was trying to change my Angular 8 meta tags dynamically for facebook sharing.
I have the back-end API on C#.
But I could not found any solution anywhere except the option of converting the existing app into server-side.
So, I am trying to host my Angular 8 universal app in the IIS of Windows Server 2019.
I have the dist folder, main.js and web.config file in the root directory of the hosted site.
I have installed the iisnode in the server.
When I browse the site a blank iisnode folder is created on the root directory.
I have set the full control permissions to IIS_IUSR and IUSR to the root directory.
But I am getting the following errors:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3rz8.png)

My folder structure is as follows :

[Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ3Cu.png)

My web.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
      <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
      </handlers>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                 <match url="/*" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="StaticContent" stopProcessing="true">  
                  <match url="([\S]+[.](jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ts|cscc|less|ico|html|map|svg))" />
                  <action type="None" />
            </rule>  
       </rules>
      </rewrite>
        <staticContent>
          <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
          <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
          <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
          <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
          <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/otf" />
         </staticContent> 
<iisnode node_env="production" nodeProcessCountPerApplication="0" nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" interceptor="C:\Program Files\iisnode\interceptor.js" />
</system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

I am stuck with the issue and not able to proceed.
Please help me.

**UPDATE (23-12-2021):**  
I made some changes in angular code and that issue is fixed. But a new error is shown which is as follows :

> iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
>
> HRESULT: 0x2 HTTP status: 500 HTTP subStatus: 1002 HTTP reason:
> Internal Server Error You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because
> system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is
> 'true'.
>
> In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process,
> consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the
> problem.
>
> The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stderr
> is shown below:
>
> Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated: Error:
> Cannot find module 'zone.js/dist/zone-node' Require stack:
>
> - C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdvAngularServer\main.js
> - C:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
>   at Object.b6Xn (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdvAngularServer\main.js:1:6605)
>   at **webpack_require** (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdvAngularServer\main.js:1:317)
>   at Module.uj+Y (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdvAngularServer\main.js:1:21026)
>   at **webpack_require** (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdvAngularServer\main.js:1:317)
>   at Object.0 (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdvAngularServer\main.js:1:2902)
>   at **webpack_require** (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AdvAngularServer\main.js:1:317)

Any idea please?

Comment: As the error message prompts, you need more information to solve your problem. You can use failed request tracking or debugging and ETW traces mentioned in the error message.

Comment: I used failed request tracking and found a message : 
`iisnode was unable to establish named pipe connection to the node.exe process before the process terminated`

Comment: Do I need to write any code for IISNode in any Angular file please? I am actually converting my regular app into universal app. Please help.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this messages, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Please check my update above in the main question. I have updated with new error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is a user "NetworkServices" or something like that... You already tried to add this user to the windows permissions? I had problems with wordpress, that i could solve with it.

I think you do not have the permission to the dist folder, or you have the wrong path in code to the module zone-node

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding `--bundleDependencies all` in the package.json.
Thanks.